# How does Windows 10 guess physical dimensions of a 1080p display?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm running Windows 10 1803 on a laptop, attached to a desktop display. Laptop's display resolution is same as the attached display, 1920x1080 pixel (namely "Full HD").  
However the screen sizes differ, the laptop has a 13" display and the desktop display is 27"...

By the settings option: `start->system->display` I can adjust scaling for each (!) display to the *lowest* scaling factor "100%" and a *highest* resolution of FullHD (1080p).  
This setting is fine for the laptop display. 
However, with the same setting for the 27" everything appears double sized ...

**Q1**: How does Windows 10 guess the (physical) dimensions of a screen display to get dpi be calculated "*per inch*"?

*Q2*: Is there any option to let Windows 10 to render a "virtual" screen resolution higher than the physical maximum on the 27" display - compare [Is there a registry hack to set virtual display resolution in Windows 10 1803?](https://superuser.com/q/1388869/784695)

*Q3*: Why does Windows 10 ignore the registry `dword` `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels`, when I set the value from initial 96ppi to a higher resolution - compare [Can I (programmatically) freeze Windows 10 scaling factor to 100% with Win8DpiScaling=1](https://superuser.com/q/1388734/784695)

*Remark*: Since I do not work on a stationary desktop, buying a 4k display is definitely no option and no answer to this topic. 
However, using 2k+ displays would solve the problem since Windows will then calculate a reasonable dpi resolution for the attached displays.

*Remark*: This is still an open topic using win2004.

Comment: A1: There is nothing to guess. Hardware has this info stored somewhere, and windows simply retrieves it.

A2 and A3: Please limit your question to 1 question. Post separate questions, unless they are very related, which in this case they are not.

Comment: Q2 moved to https://superuser.com/q/1388869/784695

Comment: Q3 moved to https://superuser.com/q/1388734/784695

Answer (score 0):

I can't really claim to have seen any Windows or driver internals.. Anyway, I know physical display size is at least being advertised in the EDID.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data

Comment: approx "fact I used to know" is:
  Win does not "start" compilation on lowest screen resolution (thats the full.HD), but only from highest available resolution screen. Due to that we cannot figure down the desired resolution, but only the highest available. Or the highest capable by win, whoever knows. 
Therefore, I suggest a software problem anyway in this usability question, no driver problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood even half the comment, anyway to calculate current dpi you'd obviously use current resolution