# Can I (programmatically) freeze Windows 10 scaling factor to 100% with Win8DpiScaling=1

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, resolution

By the Windows 10 settings option: `start->system->display` I can adjust scaling for each attached display to the *lowest* scaling factor "100%" and a *highest* resolution of FullHD (1080p), using two displays, each 1080p, display dimensions are 13" and 27".

When I modify the registry `dword` entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels` from initial 96ppi to a higher resolution, e.g. 120dpi, and additionally set the `dword` entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Win8DpiScaling` to a value of `1`, 
the scaling settings are automatically greyed out to a scaling factor of 175% after reboot and screen resolution appears as before.

Are there any options to tell Windows 10 to keep scaling factor at 100%, maybe programmatically via Visual Studio, using any .dll imports and .NET or some registry hacks ?