# Is there a registry hack to set virtual display resolution in Windows 10 1803?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-registry, resolution

I'm running Windows 10 1803 on a laptop, attached to a desktop display. Laptop's display resolution is same as the attached display, 1920x1080 pixel (namely "Full HD").  
However, the screen sizes differ, the laptop has a 13" display and the desktop display is 27"...

By the settings option: `start->system->display` I can adjust *separate* scaling for each display to the *lowest* scaling factor "100%" and a *highest* resolution of FullHD (1080p).  
This setting is fine for the laptop display. 
However, with the same setting for the 27" everything appears double sized ...

Obviously, Windows 10 gets the (physical) dimensions of a screen display to calculate dpi "*per inch*" directly from the monitor (see comment from [@LPChip](https://superuser.com/q/1388720/784695) and a hint to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data), thankfully to [@montonero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53969238/4985705)). 
Windows 10 ignores the registry `dword` `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels`, when I set the value from initial 96ppi to a higher resolution, scaling settings may be automatically greyed out to a higher scaling factor (namely 175%, compare my question about how-to [freeze Windows 10 scaling factor to 100% with Win8DpiScaling=1](https://superuser.com/q/1388734/784695)). 
Since I do not work on a stationary desktop, buying a 4k display is definitely no option and also no answer to this topic. 
 
However, using 2k+ displays would solve the problem since Windows will then calculate a reasonable dpi resolution for the attached displays.

**Question**: Is there any option to let Windows 10 to render a "virtual" screen resolution higher than the physical maximum on the 27" display?
That is, is there an option to set "height" and "weight" of 1EM in windows registry?

*Remember*: I must render contents of windows header, toolbars etc. in a lower size. And, maybe most significant for an answer, the windows taskbar takes to much space on a fullHD screen, so it should be half height after "virtualization". 
Settings in registry to downsize windows header and all fonts are also not an option, since they do not downsize programmatially fix element sizes, e.g. the MS Excel ribbon bar or the excel sheet selectors.

And whatever, just setting the scaling factor to 100% fix but a virtual resolution of LogPixels 120dpi would be fine enough as "virtual resolution". That is the same, what Windows 7 was rendering ...

Comment: Probably not really a viable option, but could you simply move the 27" monitor further from you? Since both displays have the same number of pixels, physically scaling down the larger display (by mechanism of distance) should achieve the affect you want. Otherwise... you do understand that trying to treat the 27" monitor as though it has 4x the pixels it physically contains would just make everything unreadable (due to lines disappearing when the pixels that render them don't physically exist), right? That's why you can't set a scale factor lower than 100%, as well.

Comment: The desired resolution is shown on the 13 inch laptop display. on the desk 1m in front of me. Moving the 27" away would cause me moving at 3-4m, for that the laptop display and the desktop screen just would appear same physical size. 
pls tell me where to buy those desks and help me fundraising for coworking spaces since I believe that there are plenty of FullHD screens out there somebody wanna read Excel spreadsheet contents but not the window header + ribbons bar.